# Is there a git log argument to filter files only with large changes?

Tags: git, git-log

Given that I have say 40 files in my current `git log --stat`, I want to only show those that have say 500 changes.

Example output:

```
.../MyModule.java                |   10 +
.../MySecondModule.java          |  560 +++++++++
.../MyThirdModule.java           |    5 +-
.../MyForthModule.java           |   12 +-
```

In this case I want to filter everything out except for `MySecondModule.java`. This would be a good command to run on a repo that I haven't worked on in awhile to get an idea of where any major work was done since I will likely have hundreds to thousands of changed files.

Comment: Even if there is not, it would be pretty simple to create your own filter program and run the output through it, i.e. `git log --stat | myfilter.exe`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any command line options for doing that, but as @sashoalm says, you can pipe the output to another command (or write a script) to do that kind of filtering.

This kinda works for showing files that have > 100 lines changed:

```
git log --stat | egrep "(commit|Author|Date|^    |^$|\|.*[0-9][0-9][0-9])"
```

Comment: This makes the most sense. git is developed for use on a posix environment.